# Exception trying to create WCF bindings from app.config file

Tags: web-services, wcf, app-config, wcf-binding, wcf-client

Hi I have a c# client application trying to connect to a WCF web service.    The configuration for the bindings is in the app.config file of the client.

When I call to instatiate the web service (which is an https connection) I get the following error.

Exception Details:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'TcWcfServices.ITcWcfService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   at System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
   at xx.Int.Biz.Services.TMOScheduling.TcWcfServices.TcWcfServiceClient..ctor()
```

My code simple calls

```
   if (_wcfClient == null)
        _wcfClient = new TcWcfServiceClient();
```

In my TMOSAcheduling.exe.config file I have this snippet to try and bind to the WCF service.

```
   <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_ITcWcfService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="33554432" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="33554432"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="999999999" maxStringContentLength="999999999"
            maxArrayLength="999999999" maxBytesPerRead="999999999" maxNameTableCharCount="999999999" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"
                       proxyCredentialType="None"
                       realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"
                     algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>

      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <!-- If Environment is HTTPS then use below client and comment out HTTP Client-->
    <!-- HTTPS Client -->

    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://xyz.externalhttpsAddredd.net/TcWcfServices/TcWcfServices.svc"
                behaviorConfiguration="TcWcfServicesBehavior"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_ITcWcfService"
                contract="TcWfcServices.ITcWcfService"
                name="BasicHttpsBinding_ITcWcfService" />
    </client>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TcWcfServicesBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I wondered if anyone could give me some suggestion of what the issue would be or how i might go about adding the HTTPS binding so I can instantiate and call the service.

This config file had to be "hand generated" as I was developing against a service with the same name that was not HTTPS and was also sitting on my localhost development webservice site.

Also, this client app can not run on my dev. machine because I can not reach the server URL from the dev. machine

Thanks!  I am kind of at a crunch time to get this implemented and have tried everything I can think of with similar results.

EDIT HERE IS THE SECOND CONFIG FILE

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_ITcWcfService"
       openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
       allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
  maxBufferSize="33554432" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="33554432"
  messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
  useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="999999999" maxStringContentLength="999999999"
        maxArrayLength="999999999" maxBytesPerRead="999999999" maxNameTableCharCount="999999999" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"
                   proxyCredentialType="None"
                   realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"
                 algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<client>
  <endpoint address="https://xxxxxx.testexternal.net/TcWcfServices/TcWcfServices.svc"
            behaviorConfiguration="TcWcfServicesBehavior"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"             
            contract="TcWfcServices.ITcWcfService" />
</client>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TcWcfServicesBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

```
  Second edit.  This worked but had certificate errors due to the https

  <system.serviceModel>
     <bindings>
       <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITcWcfService"
            closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
            sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            allowCookies="false"
           bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
            hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
           maxBufferSize="65536"
            maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
           maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
           messageEncoding="Text"
           textEncoding="utf-8"
           transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
        maxStringContentLength="8192"
        maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096"
        maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
       <security mode="Transport">
           <transport clientCredentialType="None"
            proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"
             algorithmSuite="Default" />
           </security>
          </binding>
       </basicHttpBinding>
     </bindings>
     <client>
       <endpoint address="https://txxxx.external.net/TcWcfServices/TcWcfServices.svc"
           binding="basicHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITcWcfService"
           contract="TcWcfServices.ITcWcfService"
           name="BasicHttpBinding_ITcWcfService" />
     </client>
   </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your <endpoing> element has a name attribute defined, so you either need to remove it to make it the "default endpoint" for that contract, or specify the endpoint name manually in the constructor of the client proxy object.

From the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731762(v=vs.110).aspx

> Optional string attribute. This attribute uniquely identifies an
>   endpoint for a given contract. You can define multiple clients for a
>   given Contract type. Each definition must be differentiated by a
>   unique configuration name. **If this attribute is omitted, the**
>   **corresponding endpoint is used as the default endpoint associated with**
>   **the specified Contract type**. The default is an empty string.

Comment: I removed the "  name="BasicHttpsBinding_ITcWcfService"    from the config and i still get an error.  it says Message = "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'TcWcfServices.ITcWcfService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because noelement matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Comment: fairly.   Some other config settings i had in the service are certainly being read from this same file.  I will include the file as I have it now in case something else stands out.

Comment: I have fixed my issue after changing a number of things.  We ended up putting an internal server up that I didnt need HTTPS.  I will post what my config file ended up being

Answer (score 0):

the answer ended up being the last edit i made but I also ended up having a cert Issue (another thing all together).  So we also ended up going to HTTP instead.

Tomasr - your suggestions were at least helpful in pointing me at some things I did not know about endpoints and the like.  And I was able to verify that I was in fact using the correct config - something I was second guessing myself.